# Clarification of Mathematical Symbols

Tags: algebraic-geometry, compactification

I was (trying to) read through Shinichi Mochizuki's paper [The Geometry Of the Compactification of the Hurwitz Scheme](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/The%20Geometry%20of%20the%20Compactification%20of%20the%20Hurwitz%20Scheme.pdf) and was stumped within just a few paragraphs by the function he defines $f : C \rightarrow \textbf{P}^1$. What is $C$ and what is $\textbf{P}^1$?

Also, what does $\textbf{Z}[\frac{1}{b!}]$ mean (referenced in the first theorem of the introduction)?

Comment: $C$ is some as of yet unspecified curve, $\mathbf{P}^1$ is the [projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line) and $\mathbf{Z}[1/b!]$ is a [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring).  If you haven't seen these things before, I think you're going to have a hard time with this paper...

Comment: The first mentioning of $f\colon C\to \bf P^1$ calls it a ramified covering of the projective line by a smooth curve. So $\bf P^1$ is the projective line, $C$ is a smooth curve, and $f$ a (ramified) covering. -$\bf Z[\frac1{b!}]$ is the ring obtained by andjoiing $\frac 1{b!}$ to the ring $\bf Z$ of integers; this could also be described as the subring of $\Bbb Q$ consisting of all fractions having no prime $>b$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thanks for the concise answer. I was told to look at the paper as an example for an assignment that is not at that level.